# Can I direcitly download an image to some cloud storage using an URL

Tags: node.js, cloud

I am working on a website where client can upload images. I use an image handler api that can finally generate an URL of the image that I need. I'm considering using cloud services for storing images. Do I really need to first use the URL to download the image to my server and then upload to the cloud? Is there any simple ways to put the image on the cloud?

The image url is temporary so I have to save it in somewhere.
I'm using node.js, express

Comment: think about it: if you don't want to proxy the data through your machine, then the image source and cloud server have to do their own direct communication. That means something on the cloud server has to reach out to the image server to do the download. So. there is no way to answer what you want, because "cloud" is a utterly meaningless/useless marketing buzzword.

Comment: make sense! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cloud were Amazon Web Services (AWS), you can upload directly from a client using HTTP POST. See [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html) with [these examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html).

You might need to create an identity with AWS Cognito, [Another link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html#Amazon_S3)

Note that if you do upload directly to the S3 bucket you would have to know the name of the file, and possibly send *that* to the server. Otherwise your file will be "in the cloud" and no one will know the name of it, so it won't be retrieved : )